# The underlying provider failed on Open. SQL Compact Edition 4 and EntityFrameWork 6, WindowsForm Application Deployment

Tags: winforms, sql-server-ce-4

I hope I will get my answer soon from experts here.

Here is my problem:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> EntityFramework
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__1() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at iSpyApplication.BLL.UserActivityLog.GetAllActivity()
>       System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\SDB001.sdf ] at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent) at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>       System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

My method which I am using to get data from database:

```
public static List<ActivityLog> GetAllActivity()
{
    try
    {
        SEDMEntities context = new SEDMEntities();
        List<ActivityLog> ag = (from m in context.ActivityLogs
                                select m).ToList();
        return ag;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MainForm.LogExceptionToFile(ex, "Exception While Getting the list of activities");
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->

  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StrantinEDMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SEDM.csdl|res://*/SEDM.ssdl|res://*/SEDM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=D:\SDB001.sdf&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>

  <runtime>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.168.0" newVersion="1.0.168.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />

  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I followed all the steps from step 1 to 7 from the below link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180734/Using-the-Microsoft-Desktop-Stack-Part-Setting-u

Here are some more details about my environment and OS.

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- ASP.NET 4 Windows Form Application
- SQL Server CE 4
- Entity Framework 6

Please let me know if you need any further detail from me.

Everything is working fine on my machine when i use VS2013 debugger to run the code.

But when I make the setup, the above error is coming.

Comment: Say the path is invalid.  Have you used File Explorer to see if that is the correct path and that SQL CE mdf file is actually in that path?